# react parent component get Count of rendered elements from switch/route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a component that will render wrapper elements of its children however it needs to know if elements are rendered as its children. I have functions ignoring Switch, Route, and the components sub-components.

```
const MAX_CHILDREN_TRAVERS = 8;
const NON_RENDABLE_ELEMENTS = ['Switch','Switch()','Route','LeftPanel','MainPanel','RightPanel'];

function findByType (children, component) {
  return children === undefined || children.length === 0 ? null : children.filter(child => component.name === getElmType(child));
};

function getElmType(elm) {
  return elm && elm.type && (elm.type.displayName || elm.type.name);
}

function getRendableChildren(elm) {
  const checkChildren = (e, count) => {
    if(count>MAX_CHILDREN_TRAVERS) {
      return e;
    }
    return NON_RENDABLE_ELEMENTS.includes(getElmType(e)) ? checkChildren(e.props.children,count++) : e;
  };
  return elm.length > 0 ? elm.map(elm => checkChildren(elm,0)) : elm;
}

function renderPanel({ children, panel, className}) {
  const myPanel = findByType(children, panel);
  return getRendableChildren(myPanel).length > 0 || myPanel === null || myPanel.length === 0 ? null : <div className={className}>{myPanel.map(el => el.props.children)}</div>;
};

export {
  findByType,
  renderPanel
};
```

This does return an array of the child elements ignoring the listed elements. However, it also will give me elements in the route that are not rendered at that path. I only want a list of elements that are being rendered at that route.

The getRendableChildren() should traverse until it finds readable elements and return them. While it's working for ignoring and passing by listed elements that I want to ignore. It can see all child elements in all routes no matter if the route is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use window.location.pathname and checked it to the Route e.props.path. I can confirm the route is active or not and exclude as needed.

```
import React from 'react';
const MAX_CHILDREN_TRAVERS = 8;
const NON_RENDABLE_ELEMENTS = ['Switch','Switch()','LeftPanel','MainPanel','RightPanel'];
const IS_ROUTE = ['Route','Route()'];

function findByType (children, component) {
  return children === undefined || children.length === 0 ? null : children.filter(child => component.name === getElmType(child));
};

function getElmType(elm) {
  return elm && elm.type && (elm.type.displayName || elm.type.name);
}

function getRendableChildren(elm) {
  const checkChildren = (e, count) => {
    if(count>MAX_CHILDREN_TRAVERS) {
      return e;
    }
    const elmType = getElmType(e);
    if(IS_ROUTE.includes(elmType)){
      const lo = window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(a => a.length);
      const pa = e.props.path.split('/').filter(a => a.length);
      return pa.every((e,i) => e === lo[i]) ? [...e.props.children] : null;
    }
    return NON_RENDABLE_ELEMENTS.includes(elmType) ? checkChildren(e.props.children,count++) : e;
  };
  return elm.length > 0 ? elm.map(elm => checkChildren(elm,0))[0] : elm;
}

function renderPanel({ children, panel, Wrapper, props}) {
  const myPanel = findByType(children, panel);
  return getRendableChildren(myPanel) === null || getRendableChildren(myPanel).length === 0 || myPanel === null || myPanel.length === 0 ? null : React.createElement(Wrapper, props, myPanel.map(el => el.props.children));
};

export {
  findByType,
  renderPanel
};
```